# Import sections of table

Tags: vba, ms-access

I need to import excel data into access, ideally using vba.
My data sometimes has a second row for units, which I do not want to include. Is there some way to accomplish this without altering the original file?

If there was some way to do this directly with DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet that would be ideal.

Specifically, I want to be able to import A1:M1 and A2:M15 as one group (for example. I will be uploading a more flexible range when I'm actually doing this)

Comment: Do the headers change?

Comment: yes, unfortunately. I need to be able to import no matter the order of the headers or naming of the headers. I will edit the field names once uploaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this may help

```
select * into [newtable2] from (
SELECT XL0.* FROM [Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes; Database=C:\TESTING.xlsx].[Sheet1$a1:e1] AS XL0 
UNION ALL 
SELECT XL1.* FROM [Excel 12.0;HDR=No; Database=C:\TESTING.xlsx].[Sheet1$a3:e10] AS XL1
)
```

Comment: I tried that (as well as using DoCmd) but it seems that when it tries to insert the data in it is still looking for matching fields even though there are no headers.

It is saying that field F1 doesnt exist. Because there were no field headers it went ahead and gave its own default header names (F1, F2, etc)

Comment: you need to build a union of the 2, sorry, i'll edit my answer

Comment: had to modify it just a bit, but it works! thank you